# What is the memory difference between serializing a value as string and serializing a value as other data type in protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto

Let's say I have a variable a, which I want to assign a decimal.
If my proto file is

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Test{
 string a = 1;
}
```

How much memory will that take and how much will be the difference if I change string a =1 to float a =1.
Is there a documentation where you can see how much memory is assigned to different datatype?

Comment: Are you interested in *memory* due to in-process object size, or *size when serialized*? They can be very, very different. For serialization size, the simplest approach would be just to test it... (Note that the string representation at least will definitely depend on the length of string you assign.)

Comment: Serialization size, how much the value is after serialization. I tried testing it, but after creating a protoc file and creating a proto object for a message, I get confused on how to serialize it, if I should use byte serialization or string serialization

Comment: We don't know what language you're using, so it's hard to give precise examples, but I'd expect you to be able to serialize to a byte array, a ByteString, a stream or something similar. Given that you're going to *have* to learn how to serialize anyway in order to use protocol buffers, I'd suggest that you focus on that long before optimizing for space.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. I was using Python and had to use SerializeToString()